# Копировать прайс по ссылке

Tags: google-docs, google-spreadsheet

Мне нужно сделать такой "посреднический" онлайн-прайс, чтобы информация копировалась от одного поставщика, добавлялось пару процентов и отображалась в моем прайсе.
 Как скопировать и добавить %?

Answer (score 0):

Напишите формулы IMPORTRANGE() https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=ru

Импортируйте таким образом у него всю колонку с ценами, рядом создайте свою колонку и пропишите формулу = цена_поставщика*1,05 (5% ваш процент). Столбец с ценами поставщика скройте. Сам файл давайте в доступ по ссылке на просмотр.